# SQL - 10 Recent placed orders

Tags: mysql

I struggle a little with the interpretation of this question. (I am a noob in sql).
This is the
[Database](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) I will be using.

I struggle with the interpretation of this question (yet very simple).

question:
*Write an sql statement that retrieves order number, customer number and customer name for the 10 most recently placed order*

```
select o.orderID,c.customerID,c.customerName
from customers c
join orders o
order by orderdate desc LIMIT 10
```

Is your interpretation similar? if not, what is your interpretation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should join based on condition to have what you want,
Try this:

```
SELECT 
   o.OrderID, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName 
FROM 
   Orders as o 
join 
   Customers as c on c.CustomerId = o.CustomerID 
order by o.OrderDate desc limit 10;
```